# Invalid Resz File. The given assembly or codebase was invalid

Tags: vb.net

after having an unfortunate accident with the replace all tool in my visual studio's solution, I've been going through the lines of code step by step. -- I basically deleted all the '>' out of my solution. Silly I know.

But more to the current issue. I've been fixing everything up, and have been able to fix almost all my forms, with the exception of this nagging error in the Reasources.resx.

> Invalid Resz File. The given assembly or codebase was invalid.

I've highlighted where this error relates to (Line 127, position 5)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" />
    <xsd:element name="root" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
      <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xsd:element name="metadata">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" use="required" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="assembly">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:attribute name="alias" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="data">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
                <xsd:element name="comment" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="3" />
              <xsd:attribute name="mimetype" type="xsd:string" msdata:Ordinal="4" />
              <xsd:attribute ref="xml:space" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
          <xsd:element name="resheader">
            <xsd:complexType>
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="value" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
              </xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            </xsd:complexType>
          </xsd:element>
        </xsd:choice>
      </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
  </xsd:schema>
  <resheader name="resmimetype">
    <value>text/microsoft-resx</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="version">
    <value>2.0</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="reader">
    <value>System.Resources.ResXResourceReader, System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</value>
  </resheader>
  <resheader name="writer">
    <value>
      System.Resources.ResXResourceWriter, System.Windows.Forms="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089">
    </value>
  </resheader>
  <assembly alias="System.Windows.Forms" name="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  <data name="ajax_loader" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\ajax-loader.gif;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>              '<---------------ERROR RELATES TO THIS LINE HERE******************
  <data name="blue_home_icon" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\blue-home-icon.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="Places_folder_icon" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\Places-folder-icon.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="Dark" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\Dark.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="no" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\no.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="minimize1" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\minimize1.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="LoadingCircle_finalani" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\LoadingCircle_finalani.gif;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="Atlas_Background_Song" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\Royalty Free="" Music="" -="" Nesser="" -="" Savanna.wav;System.IO.MemoryStream="", mscorlib="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="black_background" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\black_background.jpg;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="Actions-go-bottom-icon" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\Actions-go-bottom-icon.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="yes" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\yes.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="Places_user_identity_icon" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\Places-user-identity-icon.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="Recycle_4_2_icon" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\Recycle-4-2-icon.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="Recycle_4_1_icon" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\Recycle-4-1-icon.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="minimize" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\minimize.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="database_icon" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\database-icon.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="minimize2" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\minimize2.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="database_2no" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\database-2no.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="streamerno" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\streamerno.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    </value>
  </data>
  <data name="teamstuffno" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
    <value>
      ..\Resources\teamstuffno.png;System.Drawing.Bitmap, System.Drawing="", Version="4.0.0.0", Culture="neutral", PublicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    </value>
  </data>
</root>
```

Any help with this at all would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to delete this data/value that causes problem and re-add it from wizard or drag-drop.

Comment: Learn to use Git, commit often; whenever you'll want to reverse to a previous version of a file you will be able to do so.